# кодировка строк в Java

Tags: java, charset

Учу `Java`. При написании кода потребовалось перекодировать полученную строку. После того, как я прочитал об этом несколько постов и статей - я понял, что в `Java` строки не имеют понятия кодировки, и, если хочешь ее изменить, то нужно из строки сделать байтовый массив, в массиве поменять кодировку и полученное значение вернуть назад в строку. Получилось что то типа такого:

```
String data = "Текст который получаю";
data = new String (arr.getBytes("utf8"), "utf8");
```

Но после услышал много критики, что это типа неправильно - и вот на какие вопросы я хотел бы услышать ответ:

1. Правильно ли я все понял?
2. Правильно ли я реализую это в коде?

Comment: Вы сами ответили на свой вопрос. Есть переменная типа String, соответсвенно, String -обычный класс, который по сути инкапсулирует массив чаров и никакой переменой, хранящей информацию о кодировке там нет, в чем легко убедиться заглянув в сорцы. Поэтому ваши танцы с бубном в виде создания новой переменной типа String ни к чему не приведут. Эта переменная как не хранила инфу о кодировке,так и продолжит ее не хранить, что бы вы не делали.И это правильно, зачем создавать путаницу внутри самой Java.Вопрос кодировки возникнет тогда, когда вы работаете с внешним ресурсом-сайтом,текстовым файлом,бд...

Comment: @ДмитрийАлександрович  да работаю с внешним ресурсом изза этого вопрос. Но не понял верхний код правильно перекодирует или как?

Comment: Строки не имеют понятия кодировки, поэтому «перекодировать строку» не имеет смысла. Кодировка бывает лишь в момент превращения строки в байты и назад. Расскажите свою _настоящую_ задачу.

Comment: Если вы конвертируете байты из файла в строку неправильно, ничего не нужно делать со _строкой_. Просто сконвертируйте правильно.

Comment: @VladD задача такая что при соеденение с сокетам русские символы превразаются в чефырчку

Comment: @user8978194: Вы из сокета получаете не строку, а байты. Следовательно, вы их неправильно конвертируете в строку.

Comment: Давайте еще раз... У вас есть данные, которые вы получаете через сокет. Например, вы парсите сайт. Сам HTML хранит инфу о кодировке и в этом случае вопрос актуальный. Как только вы превратили это в переменную типа String никакой кодировки уже нет. Если вы указали ее не правильно при использовании, например, сканера, вы получите иероглифы в строковой переменной. А вы в своем коде делаете так data = new String (arr.getBytes ("utf8"), "utf8" ). Это создание строковой переменной, как бы вы ее не создавали кодировки тут никакой нет.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Кодировка это просто таблица, где каждой букве соответсвует число (помним же, что компьютер хранит только числа?). Поэтому кодировка имеет смысл только в том случае когда массив чисел (byte[], например) нам нужно превратить в строку и нужно понимать с какой буквой ассоциировать каждое число (ну или в обратную сторону).

Таким образом кодировка имеет смысл только при преобразовании в массив байтов или наоборот. Ваша запись в сокет это оно и есть.

Грубо говоря вы прочитали из сокета массив байтов:

```
byte[] data = socket.read();
```

Дальше нам нужно этои числа интрпретировать как строку, с правильной таблицей (кодировкой). В этом случае кодировка показывают в какую букву будет преобразовано каждое число:

```
new String(data, "UTF-8");
```

И наоборот у нас есть строка, и мы хотим преобразовать её к массиву байтов, мы указываем кодировку, то бишь в какое число будет преобразована каждая буковка:

```
String data = "abc";
byte[] array = data.getBytes("UTF-8");
socket.write(array);
```

Если у вас проблемы с русскими буквами - значит скорее всего указали неправильную кодировку. Какую нужно указывать - нужно разбирать что вам собственно приходит из сокета.

Comment: Всё хорошо, но поскольку из сокета читается не всё сообщение, а произвольная его часть, то у вас может прийти лишь часть байт, относящихся к тому или иному символу. Нужно сначала вычитать _всё_ сообщение, а потом уже декодировать.

Comment: А с чего это вы решили, что считывается произвольная часть байт? ) Вы же не видите типа переменной socket ))

Comment: Подозреваю, что она (переменная `socket`) представляет собой сокет, и что процедура `read` (а) читает, (б) массив байт, (в) из этого сокета. Хотя формально, да, она может делать что угодно, например, рисовать котёнка на 3d-плоттере.